# How to build a TNT Cannon with adjustable range and direction?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So far I've seen different cannon designs such as [basic guns](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/TNT_Cannons), [animal gun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeV0XB-w_yM) and the infamous [360 Gun](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-S3QH6hRRgg).

But what is an as easy as possible gun design with big range covering an angle of about 90 deg?

**EDIT**

I'm looking for concrete desings. You may provide screenshots or vids along with a short description.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, just make something which has room for multiple slots of tnt, and adjust the amount for the range. For direction, it's a bit trickier, but you can have multiple openings to the cannon, plug the ones not in use, etc.

Comment: I'm looking for concrete designs - have you some?

Answer (score -2):

to change the range you can change the angle of the shot. to do this you have to raise the block that the shot sits on, this can be done using a piston or by hand.

Comment: This is hardly an answer to the question. Can you expand on this?